# Insert rows in Pandas DF conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, primavera

I am exporting a schedule from P6, and am in the process of cleaning the data in Excel in prep for another application. I created a new column titled 'Parent', and am using that as the basis for my grouping.

The application I am going to use for this dataframe is Milestones Professional, which requires parent rows in the dataframe in order to indent properly. I have a column titled 'Parent', and any group which has a sub-parent is identified like the following: "Parent name > Sub-Parent name> etc."

```
import pandas as pd

#example of current dateframe

data = [['Milestone 1', 'Major Milestones', '01/01/2022', '01/02/2022'], ['Milestone 2', 'Major Milestones 2', '01/03/2022', '01/04/2022'], ['Milestone 3', 'Major Milestones>April MS', '01/05/2022', '01/06/2022'], ['Milestone 4', 'Major Milestones>April MS', '01/07/2022', '01/07/2022'], ['Milestone 5', 'Late Milestones', '01/08/2022', '01/09/2022'], ['Milestone 7', 'Late Milestones', '01/09/2022', '01/10/2022'], ['Milestones 8', 'Late Milestones>June MS', '01/13/2022', '01/14/2022'], ['Milestone 9', 'Late Milestones>June MS', '01/15/2022', '01/16/2022'], ['Milestone 10', 'Late Milestones>July MS', '01/19/2022', '01/20/2022']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Activity', 'Parent', 'Start', 'Finish'])

df
```

```
   Activity       Parent                     Start       Finish
0  Milestone 1    Major Milestones           01/01/2022  01/02/2022
1  Milestone 2    Major Milestones 2         01/03/2022  01/04/2022
2  Milestone 3    Major Milestones>April MS  01/05/2022  01/06/2022
3  Milestone 4    Major Milestones>April MS  01/07/2022  01/07/2022
4  Milestone 5    Late Milestones            01/08/2022  01/09/2022
5  Milestone 7    Late Milestones            01/09/2022  01/10/2022
6  Milestones 8   Late Milestones>June MS    01/13/2022  01/14/2022
7  Milestone 9    Late Milestones 9          01/15/2022  01/16/2022
8  Milestone 10   Late Milestones>July MS    01/19/2022  01/20/2022
```

#ideal dataframe

```
data_1 = [['Major Milestones', '', '01/01/2022', '01/07/2022'], ['Milestone 1', 'Major Milestones', '01/01/2022', '01/02/2022'], ['Milestone 2', 'Major Milestones', '01/03/2022', '01/04/2022'], ['April MS', '', '01/05/2022', '01/07/2022'], ['Milestone 3', 'Major Milestones>April MS', '01/05/2022', '01/06/2022'], ['Milestone 4', 'Major Milestones>April MS', '01/07/2022', '01/07/2022'], ['Late Milestones', '', '01/08/2022', '01/20/2022'], ['Milestone 5', 'Late Milestones', '01/08/2022', '01/09/2022'], ['June MS', '', '01/11/2022', '01/14/2022'],  ['Milestone 6', 'Late Milestones>June MS', '01/10/2022', '01/11/2022'], ['Milestone 7', 'Late Milestones>June MS', '01/09/2022', '01/10/2022'], ['Milestones 8', 'Late Milestones>June MS', '01/13/2022', '01/14/2022'], ['Milestone 9', 'Late Milestones>June MS', '01/15/2022', '01/16/2022'], ['July MS', '', '01/17/2022', '01/20/2022'], ['Milestone 10', 'Late Milestones>July MS', '01/19/2022', '01/20/2022']]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns=['Activity', 'Parent', 'Start', 'Finish'])

df_1
```

```
       Activity                Parent                      Start       Finish
0  Major Milestones                                 01/01/2022  01/07/2022
1  Milestone 1         Major Milestones           01/01/2022  01/02/2022
2  Milestone 2         Major Milestones           01/03/2022  01/04/2022
3  April MS                                         01/05/2022  01/07/2022
4  Milestone 3         Major Milestones>April MS   01/05/2022  01/06/2022
5  Milestone 4         Major Milestones>April MS   01/07/2022  01/07/2022
6  Late Milestones                                  01/08/2022  01/20/2022
7  Milestone 5         Late Milestones            01/08/2022  01/09/2022
8  June MS                                           01/11/2022  01/14/2022
9  Milestone 6         Late Milestones>June MS     01/10/2022  01/11/2022
10 Milestone 7         Late Milestones>June MS     01/09/2022  01/10/2022
11 Milestones 8        Late Milestones>June MS     01/13/2022  01/14/2022
12 Milestone 9         Late Milestones>June MS     01/15/2022  01/16/2022
13 July MS                                           01/17/2022  01/20/2022
14 Milestone 10        Late Milestones>July MS     01/19/2022  01/20/2022
```

I am trying to insert new rows identifying the major parent above the different groups, plant the start and finish date for that group, and also put rows identifying the sub-parents and the start and finish dates for those groups (sorry I know that's probably worded terribly). I tried creating a condition that searches in the parent column and creates a new row with the name of the parent for each group above but with no success.

My apologies for the formatting of the previous code snippet, it didn't come over well from VS.

Comment: Thanks for your question! :) It also helps to make data in a way that someone can copy + paste it :)

Comment: @Roelant sorry for the format of the first post, you should be able to copy + paste the above code now.

Comment: You example is ambiguous, why are trailing numbers ignored? Why does "Milestones 9" become a "Late Milestones>June MS"? What happens if you have more than one parent level?

Comment: @mozway sorry I didn't intend to leave the that without a parent.  I added the appropriate parent (Late Milestones>June MS.  Having more than one parent is where the procedure is going to get tricky, I need to have sub-groups for each parent level, with the sub-parent heading above each group as seen above.  Late Milestones is the main parent, and June MS and July MS are sub-parents in the Late Milestones group.

Comment: Are you sure a DataFrame is the right format? I would personally model this type of data as some sort of tree (or nested dicts)...

Comment: @MatteoZanoni yes the data is in the right format.  I pulled it from excel and imported as PD, it was previously formatted as a table

Comment: @bcoder I understand your input is a DataFrame, I was wandering if outputting to a DataFrame also is the right choice. It looks like you are trying to fit a tree-like structure into a table. Maybe your output should be in some other format?

Comment: @MatteoZanoni sorry I misunderstood.  What format would you recommend?

Comment: Your output data looks more like a tree to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the original propose format, you could use `extract`, slicing and `concat`:

```
s = df['Parent'].str.extract('>(.*)$', expand=False).fillna(df['Parent'])
out = pd.concat([s[s.ne(s.shift())].to_frame(name='Activity'), df]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
           Activity                     Parent       Start      Finish
0  Major Milestones                        NaN         NaN         NaN
0       Milestone 1           Major Milestones  01/01/2022  01/02/2022
1       Milestone 2           Major Milestones  01/03/2022  01/04/2022
2          April MS                        NaN         NaN         NaN
2       Milestone 3  Major Milestones>April MS  01/05/2022  01/06/2022
3       Milestone 4  Major Milestones>April MS  01/07/2022  01/07/2022
4   Late Milestones                        NaN         NaN         NaN
4       Milestone 5            Late Milestones  01/08/2022  01/09/2022
5       Milestone 7            Late Milestones  01/09/2022  01/10/2022
6           June MS                        NaN         NaN         NaN
6      Milestones 8    Late Milestones>June MS  01/13/2022  01/14/2022
7       Milestone 9    Late Milestones>June MS  01/15/2022  01/16/2022
8           July MS                        NaN         NaN         NaN
8      Milestone 10    Late Milestones>July MS  01/19/2022  01/20/2022
```

Comment: that's also a good solution, would I be able to plant the start and finish dates for the different groups in the parent rows?  For example, the Start and Finish dates for June MS would be 1/13/2022 and 1/16/2022

Comment: @bcoder yes of course, but the logic wasn't fully clear

Comment: what method would you recommend to accomplish that @mozway? I can clarify on the logic if necessary

Comment: I'd use a `groupby.agg` and `merge`

Comment: I've been experimenting with your above solution, and when working with my actual data I'm having an issue with the sorting.  When I perform the sort_values() function, it is placing the parent rows below the row it's supposed to be at.  For example,  the equivalent of the Late Milestones in the example above is being placed below Milestone 5 (instead of above).  When my index has duplicates as above, for some reason it is placing the row being merged below the original row (instead of above).  Is there a sort method where I can specify how duplicate indices are sorted?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use multi-index here instead of adding rows. Continuing on your script, you can do:

```
# retrieve name of the parent milestones
df["Major Milestones"] = df["Parent"].str.replace(".*>|\s\d", "", regex=True)

multi_index_df = df.set_index(["Major Milestones", "Activity"], drop=True)
```

The result looks like :

```
                                              Parent  ...      Finish
Major Milestones Activity                                 ...            
Major Milestones Milestone 1            Major Milestones  ...  01/02/2022
                 Milestone 2          Major Milestones 2  ...  01/04/2022
April MS         Milestone 3   Major Milestones>April MS  ...  01/06/2022
                 Milestone 4   Major Milestones>April MS  ...  01/07/2022
Late Milestones  Milestone 5             Late Milestones  ...  01/09/2022
                 Milestone 7             Late Milestones  ...  01/10/2022
June MS          Milestones 8    Late Milestones>June MS  ...  01/14/2022
                 Milestone 9     Late Milestones>June MS  ...  01/16/2022
July MS          Milestone 10    Late Milestones>July MS  ...  01/20/2022
```

You can now add the start and finish time per major milestone like this:

```
multi_index_df["Major Start"] = None
multi_index_df["Major Finish"] = None

for df3_key, df3 in multi_index_df.groupby("Major Milestones"):
    multi_index_df.loc[df3_key, "Major Start"] = df3["Start"].head(1).values[0]
    multi_index_df.loc[df3_key, "Major Finish"] = df3["Start"].tail(1).values[0]
```